# How to let react-native picker showing items directly instead of dropdown box?

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-picker](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker). In iOS it displays as

[image]

I expect android could have the same UI but it always shows a dropdown box

[image]

Is there any library to support UI in Android the same way as iOS?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested these packages on Android, but have you tried them?

1. [Smooth Picker](https://github.com/rdhox/react-native-smooth-picker)
2. [React Native Scrollable Picker](https://github.com/reactseals/react-native-scrollable-picker)
3. [ScrollView Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-scrollview-picker)
4. [Scroll Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-scroll-picker)

Let me know if they work for you.